# Divs are longer on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Hello I am working on a project. I have found an annoying bug on IE later on. The css works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but on IE(not edge) it looks very weird.

The div's are very long at the middle of the page and looks not good.
Does somebody know a good solution for this? I am using bootstrap by the way.

This is the project : [Osolemio](http://osolemio.bsenn.nl)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rxDN.png)

```
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
    <a href="http://osolemio.bsenn.nl/images/pizza/sate-pizza.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Pizza sate">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://osolemio.bsenn.nl/images/pizza/sate-pizza.png" alt="Card image cap">
    </a>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold">Pizza Quattro Formaggi</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <h5 class="position-absolute">$24.99</h5>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Toevoegen</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The solution for me was :

> style="flex-shrink:0;"

```
<a style="flex-shrink:0;" href="{{asset($product->imagePath)}}" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Pizza sate">
    <img class="card-img-top"  src="{{asset($product->imagePath)}}" alt="Card image cap">
</a>
```

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of problem? I don't have access to IE at the moment, but in the past, I've had bugs because you need to be more explicit with default values.

Comment: You have some errors in your html. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fosolemio.bsenn.nl%2F

Comment: Thanks @mlegg I will try to fix these errors asap :)

Comment: @mrcharlie added a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `max-height` to a static size will work if the images are all the same and static, but if you want something a little more dynamic you can try either of these solutions:

Set `flex-shrink: 0` **or** `overflow: hidden` on the `card > a` tag.

The original size of the image is 600px tall and I think thats why IE has that large whitespace... its calculations are off I guess for `height:auto`

Answer (score 1):

Apply this style "**max-height: 200px**", inline or in some class for this element:

```
<a style="max-height: 200px;" href="http://osolemio.bsenn.nl/images/pizza/sate-pizza.png" 
data-title="Pizza sate" 
data-lightbox="image-1">
<img class="card-img-top" alt="Card image cap" src="http://osolemio.bsenn.nl/images/pizza/sate-pizza.png">
</a>
```

It's not the best solution, but give you time until you find the solution. IE makes me sad :(

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I already thought about this, but like you said it is not the best solution. The best way I have found is 

flex-shrink: 0;